# PHP, Javascript & Ajax query

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm developing a simple filter setup for a side project and have come up to a roadblock.

I'm using the following code to pass a variable to a second php file which does a database query based on the 'GET' variable that has been passed.

```
<?PHP 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","*********","***********");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("drwho", $con);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript">
   function updateCompanions(str)
   {
      var xmlhttp;

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } 

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
          document.getElementById("randomStoryCompanionWrapper").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }

      xmlhttp.open("GET","updateCompanions.php?doctorID="+str, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
  }  
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.php" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/randomStory.css" />


<title>Doctor Who Thingy</title>
</head>

<body>

<section id="pageWrapper">

<header></header>

<section id="pageContent">

<section id="pageMainDisplay">

<section id="randomStoryDoctorWrapper">
<section class="randomStorySelectTitle">Doctor</section>

<?PHP
$dValue = 1;
$selectedDoctor = "";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM doctors ORDER BY doctorid");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

    $doctorID       = $row['doctorid'];
    $doctorTitle    = $row['doctorName'];

?>

    <button class="randomStorySelectDoctorIcon" value="<?PHP echo $dValue;?>" onclick="updateCompanions(this.value);"><?PHP echo $doctorTitle;?></button>

<?PHP
    $dValue++;
    }
    echo "<section class='end'></section>";
    echo "</section>";  
?>

<section id="randomStoryCompanionWrapper">
<section class="randomStorySelectTitle">Companion(s)</section>
<section class="randomStorySelectTitle">No Doctor selected</section>
<section class="end"></section>
</section>

<section id="randomStoryMonsterWrapper">
<section class="randomStorySelectTitle">Monster/Adversary</section>
<section class="randomStorySelectTitle"><?PHP echo $selectedDoctor; ?>    </section>
<section class="end"></section>
</section>

</section>
<section id="pageAdDisplay">
    <section id="pageGoogleAd">Google Ad space</section>
    <section id="pageGoogleAd">Random Amazon Item</section>
    <section id="pageGoogleAd">Random BBC Item</section>
    <section id="pageGoogleAd">Random Big Finish Item</section>
    <section id="pageGoogleAd">Random Comixology Item</section>
</section>
</section>
<footer>Footer</footer>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I'm having is getting the 'GET' variable sent back to the original page.

ie.  I need to have a new variable '$selectedItem' be populated with the value contained in the 'str' variable that the Javascript function is using.

In my head, it seems as though just assigning the 'GET' variable to the new variable in the 'updateCompanions.php' file would do it, but it doesn't seem to return the variable.

Would anyone know of how, or even if it is possible? (I know the difference between Javascript and PHP in terms of where the processing happens and that passing variables from Javascript to PHP is tricky :))

Thanks
Paul

---

Here is the code for updateCompanions.php

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","*********","*********");
if (!$con)
  {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("********", $con);

$doctorID = $_GET['doctorID'];

if (strlen($doctorID) < 2)
{
   $doctorID = "0" . $doctorID;
}

echo "<section class='randomStorySelectTitle'>Companion(s)</section>";

$companions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM companions WHERE companionDoctor LIKE '%$doctorID%' ORDER BY companionid");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($companions))
    {

    $companionID        = $row['companionid'];
    $companionTitle     = $row['companionTitle'];

    echo "<button class='randomStorySelectCompanionIcon' value='" . $companionID . " onclick='updateMonsters(this.value);>" . $companionTitle . "</button>";
    }

echo "<section class='end'></section>";

?>
```

Comment: You cannot send back GET variable, you have to return response in JSON or in HTML and do logic based on response in Javascript

Comment: Show your code for `updateCompanions.php`. It is a little hard to follow what you want, but it might be as simple as `<?php $selectedItem = $_GET['doctorID']; echo $selectedItem; ?>`

Comment: Have you confirmed that the JS `str` variable contains the value you expect?

Comment: Do you have an element with `id="randomStoryCompanionWrapper"` on the current page?

Comment: What result do you actually get? Presumably the innerHTML of randomStoryCompanionWrapper is changed. What is it changed to?

Comment: How are you calling the JS function? Are you doing anything else at the same time that might have side effects (such as following a link)?

Comment: JS variable str does contain the correct info.  http://www.themightyspud.co.uk/drwho/randomStory.php shows what it looks like at the moment, and it works exactly as it should.  The thing I need is to 'change' the variable that gets passed to the JS function into a PHP variable to allow the next stage of the filter to work properly

Comment: Show your updateCompanions.php?doctorID= script

Comment: The list of companion buttons is changing. That is the result of changing that variable in the updateCompanions.php script. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: My apologies, I don't think I've explained it very well.  The code that I've posted works exactly as it should (as the url posted earlier shoes), so there's no problems there.  The problem is, for the next stage of the filtering I need the value of 'str' which is determined by a button click to be available (in php) to the set of buttons that are generated in the 'updateCompanions.php' file but which are displayed in the main 'index.php' file (first code block) (which I will update in a moment to contain the full code).